# Finding the flaw in a reduction from Hamiltonian cycle to Hamiltonian cycle on bipartitie graphs

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

I'm trying to solve a problem for class that is stated like so:

> A bipartite graph is an undirected graph in which every cycle has even
>   length.  We attempt to show that the Hamiltonian cycle (a cycle that
>   passes through each node exactly once) problem polynomially reduces to
>   the Hamiltonian cycle problem in bipartite graphs. We need a function
>   $T:  \{\text{graphs}\} \to \{\text{bipartite graphs}\}$ such that $T$ can be computed in
>   polynomial time and for any graph $G$, $G$ has Hamiltonian cycle iff $T(G)$
>   has a Hamiltonian cycle. Let $T(G)$ be the bipartite graph obtained by
>   inserting a new vertex on every edge. What is wrong with this
>   transformation?

I think the problem with the transformation is that for $T(G)$ you need to insert an edge between each pair of vertices and not just insert a new vertex on every edge. I'm actually a bit stumped by this one. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try the graph `a-b, b-c, c-d, d-a, a-c` by hand.

Comment: This problem doesn't make sense.  How do you put a new vertex on every edge? A new vertex z s.t. if x->y, then x->z->y?

Comment: [spinning_plate](http://stackoverflow.com/users/597310/spinning-plate) gives a hint for a working transformation: “how can you make a bipartite graph from an arbitrary graph?”

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that a Hamiltonian cycle has to pass through **all** vertices: if the cycle in the original graph does not take some edge $e$, then the vertex you split $e$ with will not be taken if you take the same route. This means that the resulting cycle is not Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a graphic illustration of the problem
after changing the diagonal line with edge-vertex-edge there isn't a Ham-Cycle

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Is it possible that the transformation is correct but pointless? Consider [Barnette's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnette%27s_conjecture):

> If a planar graph is bipartite and cubic but only 2-connected, then it may be non-Hamiltonian, and it is NP-complete to test Hamiltonicity for these graphs.

(possibly taken out of context - check back with the Wikipedia entry). Is it possible that all you are doing is reducing one known NP-complete problem to another known NP-complete problem?