# Complexity of two cycles which differ by $1$ in length

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np-hard, np

Given an undirected graph $G(V,E)$, our problem asks whether $G$ contains $2$ simple cycles which differ by $1$ in length.

What is the complexity of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It belongs to NP obviously, and is NP-complete by a reduction from [the Hamilton cycle problem on bipartite graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18335/proof-that-the-existence-of-a-hamilton-path-in-a-bipartite-graph-is-np-complete).

Given a bipartite graph with $2n$ vertices, add an isolated simple cycle of length $2n+1$. Since there is no odd cycle in a bipartite graph, the new graph has two cycles which differ by 1 in length if and only if there is a Hamilton cycle in the bipartite graph.

Comment: Quite simple. How can I miss this!